# Calendar Booking Using Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I recently came across a video from Kurt Kaiser where he goes through the process of creating an Appointment Booking System.

I'm new to coding and I followed his steps along with having the code that he has shared and I cannot seem to get this to work. For some reason after I submit the form and approve the request it never puts the event in my calendar.

I'm calling the calendar in the script I made by the ID. Is there something else I need to do after I create the calendar in order for this to work?

Do I need to make my calendar public in google?

Again I followed his instruction video to the T and still don't get the events in the calendar.

I also get an error for name under the :// Creates a calendar event using the submitted data in the code below, I believe it said it wasn't defined. But maybe that's because I was just running the script?

I have tried to reach out to the author of the code but he has not responded.

Again he has freely shared this code from his website.
Any help would greatly be appreciated as I have been pulling my hair out on this project and trying to come up with a booking system that uses google forms for my team.

```
 `// Calendar Reservation Approval System
    // Kurt Kaiser, 2018
    // All Rights Reserved

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

    **// Calendar to output requests
    var calendar =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById('bfpkrilvj3avj0srbelt3n89rc@group.calendar.google.com');**

    // Creates an object from the last form submission
    function Submission(row){
    this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    this.name = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
    this.reason = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
    this.date = new Date(sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue());
    this.dateString = (this.date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + 
    this.date.getDate() + '/' + this.date.getYear();
    this.time = sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue();
    this.timeString = this.time.toLocaleTimeString();
    this.email = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
    // Adjust time and make end time
    this.date.setHours(this.time.getHours());
    this.date.setMinutes(this.time.getMinutes());
    this.endTime = new Date(this.date);
    this.endTime.setHours(this.time.getHours() + 2);
    }

    // Check for conflicting events
    function getConflicts(request) {
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
    if (conflicts.length < 1) {
    request.status = "New";
    } else {
    request.status = "Conflict";
    sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn - 1).setValue("Reject");
    sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn).setValue("Sent: Conflict");
     }
    }

    // Convert data of status and notified columns into array
    function StatusObject(){
    this.statusArray = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn -1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
    this.notifiedArray = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn, lastRow, 1).getValues();
    this.statusArray = [].concat.apply([], this.statusArray);
  this.notifiedArray = [].concat.apply([], this.notifiedArray);
}

// Get the index of the row that has had a status change
function getChangeIndex(statusChange){
  statusChange.index = statusChange.notifiedArray.indexOf("");
  statusChange.row = statusChange.index + 1;
  if (statusChange.index == -1){
    return;
  } else if (statusChange.statusArray[statusChange.index] != "") {
    statusChange.status = statusChange.statusArray[statusChange.index];
    sheet.getRange(statusChange.row, lastColumn).setValue("Sent: " + statusChange.status);
    statusChange.notifiedArray[statusChange.index] = "update";
  } else {
    statusChange.status = statusChange.statusArray[statusChange.index];
    statusChange.notifiedArray[statusChange.index] = "no update";
  }
}

// Draft contents for emails depending on needed message
function draftEmail(request){
  request.buttonLink = "button URL" // I would have the URL in place here for the button
  request.buttonText = "New Request";
  switch (request.status) {
    case "New":
      request.subject = "Request for " + request.dateString + " Appointment Received";
      request.header = "Request Received";
      request.message = "Once the request has been reviewed you will receive an email updating you on it.";
      break;
    case "New2":
      request.email = "myemail@address.com";
      request.subject = "New Request for " + request.dateString;
      request.header = "Request Received";
      request.message = "A new request needs to be reviewed.";
      request.buttonLink = "https://link to the spreadsheet";// I would have the URL to my spreadsheet here
      request.buttonText = "View Request";
      break;
    case "Approve":
      request.subject = "Confirmation: Appointment for " + request.dateString + " has been scheduled";
      request.header = "Confirmation";
      request.message = "Your appointment has been scheduled.";
      break;
    case "Conflict":
      request.subject = "Conflict with " + request.dateString + " Appointment Request";
      request.header = "Conflict";
      request.message = "There was a scheduling conflict. Please reschedule.";
      request.buttonText = "Reschedule";
      break;
    case "Reject":
      request.subject = "Update on Appointment Requested for " + request.dateString;
      request.header = "Reschedule";
      request.message = "Unfortunately the request times does not work. Could "+
        "we reschedule?";
      request.buttonText = "Reschedule";
      break;
  }
}

// Creates a calendar event using the submitted data
function updateCalendar(request){
  var event = calendar.createEvent(
    request.name,
    request.date,
    request.endTime
    )
}

// Send Email
function sendEmail(request){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: request.email,
    subject: request.subject,
    htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
  })
}

// --------------------  Main Functions ---------------------
function onFormSubmission(){
  var request = new Submission(lastRow);
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  sendEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "New"){
    request.status = "New2";
    draftEmail(request);
    sendEmail(request);
  }
}

// Triggered function to check if any status has changed
function onEdit(){
  var statusChange = new StatusObject();
  while (true){
    getChangeIndex(statusChange);
    if (statusChange.index == -1){
      return;
    } else {
      var request = new Submission(statusChange.row);
      if (statusChange.status){
        request.status = statusChange.status;
        if (statusChange.status == "Approve"){
          updateCalendar(request);
        }
        draftEmail(request);
        sendEmail(request);
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Did you create an onFormSubmit trigger for the spreadsheet with the linked sheet for the onFormSubmission function?

Comment: Yes it was created along with a second one of onEdit trigger

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do this a little differently:

```
function onFormSubmission(e){
  var request = new Submission(e.range.rowStart);//this determines which row the form just modified
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  sendEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "New"){
    request.status = "New2";
    draftEmail(request);
    sendEmail(request);
  }
}
```

also the below onEdit function cannot just be a simple trigger because some of the functions require permission.  This will have to be an installable trigger and don't forget to change the name when you create the installable trigger otherwise the function will get two triggers a simple trigger and an installable trigger

```
function onEdit(){
  var statusChange = new StatusObject();
  while (true){
    getChangeIndex(statusChange);
    if (statusChange.index == -1){
      return;
    } else {
      var request = new Submission(statusChange.row);
      if (statusChange.status){
        request.status = statusChange.status;
        if (statusChange.status == "Approve"){
          updateCalendar(request);
        }
        draftEmail(request);
        sendEmail(request);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above function must complete in 30 seconds.  Actually I should say the above function will stop after 30 seconds whether it's complete or not

There have been a lot of changes to Google Apps Script since 2018 so some of this code may not work.  Especially, with the new ES6.

I'm thinking that your missing an updateCalendar

```
function onFormSubmission(){
  var request = new Submission(lastRow);
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  sendEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "New"){
    updateCalendar(request);//added this line
    request.status = "New2";
    draftEmail(request);
    sendEmail(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, thats what I thought, that the code may no longer work. The big question here is why don't I get an update to the calendar? Will the code you posted here resolve that issue?

Comment: Oh and yes I did create the onFormSubmit trigger along with a onedit trigger

Comment: It's hard to say.  I haven't looked through all of the code carefully. My observations so far were from a simple read of your question.

Comment: everything else seemed to work other than the event being added to my calendar. I had copied the calendar ID from the calendar settings and pasted that into the code. Again, I'm not a programer and was just looking for an easy way to create a form that a user could fill out to populate my calendar and may as an extra bonus send and automated email that it was done. I thought this code that was shared out was just what I was looking for. I send the emails and can approve the time but nothing shows up on that calendar. I have no problem digging in and trying to figure the code but I'm stumped.

Comment: I think you're missing an `updateCalendar()` in the form submission function.

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Okay I was doing some testing and there is a line in the code where I can adjust the end time right now its set to +2 `this.endTime.setHours(this.time.getHours() + 2);' what would be the best way I can set that to an hour and a half? I tried using 1.5 and it wont work.

Comment: Try using this.endTime.setMinutes(90)